# How to plot an integral in Mathematica?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I need to graph this integral:[integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFPxa.png)

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[x], {x, 1, Infinity}]
```

Can someone help me?

I need to prove this [inequality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn0BB.png) with a graph

```
Sum[1/Sqrt[n], {n, 2, Infinity}] > 
 Integrate[1/Sqrt[x], {x, 1, Infinity}]
```

The summation i plot it with:

```
b = Table[Sum[1/sqrt(n),{k,n}],{n,2,100}]
ListPlot[b]
```

but I do not know how to do with the integral

Comment: The integral is divergent, so what exactly do you mean by graphing it?

Answer (score 2):

Please post formulas as code not as images.  Here is a plot:

```
f = Function[x, 1./Sqrt[x]]
ll = 1
ul = 5
Plot[f[x], {x, ll, ul}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Filling -> Axis]
```

The shaded area corresponds to

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, ll, ul}]
```

If you change `ul` to `Infinity`, this integral will not evaluate even though

```
0==Limit[f[x], x -> Infinity]
```

That is, as observed by @Rohit, the integral diverges.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep it in mind for the next one. It's just what I was looking for, thanks!